# Polymorphic OneToMany images-products relationship, how to know which images is which?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

For a personal project I am trying to create a webshop using laravel.
I have a products table and an images table who have a One To Many Polymorphic Relationship.
Some products are different and might only need one image, and others need to be able to have multiple.
I am struggling to find a way to know which image is which. For example, one image might be the thumbnail of a product, the other might be some image of a part of the product, etc. Should I make a new table image_types and store the id in my images table, or is this not effective?

Products table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('stock', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_category_id');
            $table->foreign('product_category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('account_type_id');
            $table->foreign('account_type_id')->references('id')->on('account_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Images table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->morphs('imageable');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not what polymorphic relationships are for. Your products can have 1 or more image, which is just a standard non-polymorphic `hasMany` relationship. Can one specific image be used by more than a single product?

Comment: All products would have unique images.

Comment: Then it's just a `hasMany` relationship.

Comment: Alright, so how should I design my database for this, to be able to add for example a thumbnail and another image to one product, and only a thumbnail to another?

Comment: Set the relationships up in your models.

Answer (score 0):

```
# images migration file
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->string('url');
        // Maybe add the following column if you really need to be able
        // to tell the difference between what is and isn't a thumbnail.
        // $table->enum('type', ['thumbnail', 'other']);

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}
```

```
# Image model
class Image extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        // an Image belongs to a Product, using the foreign key 'product_id'
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

```
# Product model
class Product extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        // a Product has one or many images (Image), using the foreign key 'product_id'
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

```
$product = Product::find($product_id);
// get a collection of all the Product's images
$product->images
```

```
$image = Image::find($image_id);
// get THE product this image belongs to
$image->product
```

More reading:

- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse
- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: I appreciate your answer, only some products need to be able to have up to 7 different pictures, for example a car, I will need some pictures of the inside, of the tires, etc and I need to categorize those pictures on the product detail page

Comment: Those kind of limits should be part of your business logic. Do the appropriate validation when you store a new Product (and it's images).

Answer (score 0):

for save multiple images for a product you save urls of images in a column as array string
for this goal you must cast the column of url in Image model like following:

```
protected $casts = [
    'url' => 'array' // when set the url it convert to string and when get data it convert to array
];
```

then when you wnat to save image urls, set key for any type of image for example for set thumbnail and original image do the following:

```
$urlArray = [];
$urlArray['thumbnail'] = $thumbnailUrl;
$urlArray['original'] = $originalUrl;
```

this is a simple example, you can with this way set key for any type of image even you want to save several size for thumbnail image you can do the following:

```
$urlArray['thumbnail']['240'] = $thumbnailUrlLow; // or set key ['thumbnailLow']
$urlArray['thumbnail']['320'] = $thumbnailUrlMed;
$urlArray['thumbnail']['480'] = $thumbnailUrlHigh;
```

for get a thumbnail urls of a product do following:

```
$image->url['thumbnail']['320']
```

for get original iamge size:

```
$iamge->url['original'];
```

you can set many key do a lot with set keys for any type of image of product.

don't forget define `protected $casts` for target column and set convert to array when to get it.